# InvalidArgumentError for training a character model using Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to make a Arabic poetry classification model, since the vocabulary is too big to go for word-model I am trying to model it using character-model RNN. The goal is to predict the poet from the poem text. The model was working okay when going for word-model but there are issues when trying to use character-model as shown below.

Data shape and neural network:

> Train ---> X = (39053, 1000) | Y = (39053, 484)

> Validation ---> X = (8369, 1000) | Y = (8369, 484)

> Test ---> X (8369, 1000) | Y = (8369, 484)

```
maxlen = 1000
vocab_size = 70 + 1
model = keras.Sequential([

  keras.Input(shape=(maxlen,)),
  keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, output_dim=256, input_length=maxlen),
  keras.layers.Bidirectional(keras.layers.GRU(256, return_sequences=True)),
  keras.layers.Bidirectional(keras.layers.GRU(256, return_sequences=True)),
  keras.layers.Bidirectional(keras.layers.GRU(256)),
  keras.layers.Dense(256, 'relu'),
  keras.layers.Dense(484, 'softmax')            )]

opt = keras.optimizers.Adam()
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(x=trainx, y=trainy, batch_size=64, validation_data=(valx, valy), epochs=20, class_weight=d_class_weights)
```

I get the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument:  indices[48,99] = -1 is not in [0, 71)
     [[node sequential_10/embedding_10/embedding_lookup (defined at <ipython-input-147-bda858e4c00c>:1) ]]
  (1) Invalid argument:  indices[48,99] = -1 is not in [0, 71)
     [[node sequential_10/embedding_10/embedding_lookup (defined at <ipython-input-147-bda858e4c00c>:1) ]]
     [[Adam/Adam/update/AssignSubVariableOp/_37]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_97424]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node sequential_10/embedding_10/embedding_lookup:
 sequential_10/embedding_10/embedding_lookup/91094 (defined at /usr/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py:112)

Input Source operations connected to node sequential_10/embedding_10/embedding_lookup:
 sequential_10/embedding_10/embedding_lookup/91094 (defined at /usr/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py:112)

Function call stack:
train_function -> train_function
```

and here's the full trace:

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-147-bda858e4c00c> in <module>()
----> 1 history = model.fit(x=trainx, y=trainy, batch_size=64, validation_data=(valx, valy), epochs=20, class_weight=d_class_weights)

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1098                 _r=1):
   1099               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1100               tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
   1101               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1102                 context.async_wait()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    826     tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()
    827     with trace.Trace(self._name) as tm:
--> 828       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    829       compiler = "xla" if self._experimental_compile else "nonXla"
    830       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    886         # Lifting succeeded, so variables are initialized and we can run the
    887         # stateless function.
--> 888         return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
    889     else:
    890       _, _, _, filtered_flat_args = \

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2941        filtered_flat_args) = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   2942     return graph_function._call_flat(
-> 2943         filtered_flat_args, captured_inputs=graph_function.captured_inputs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   2944 
   2945   @property

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
   1917       # No tape is watching; skip to running the function.
   1918       return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
-> 1919           ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
   1920     forward_backward = self._select_forward_and_backward_functions(
   1921         args,

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in call(self, ctx, args, cancellation_manager)
    558               inputs=args,
    559               attrs=attrs,
--> 560               ctx=ctx)
    561         else:
    562           outputs = execute.execute_with_cancellation(

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     62     if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument:  indices[48,99] = -1 is not in [0, 71)
     [[node sequential_10/embedding_10/embedding_lookup (defined at <ipython-input-147-bda858e4c00c>:1) ]]
  (1) Invalid argument:  indices[48,99] = -1 is not in [0, 71)
     [[node sequential_10/embedding_10/embedding_lookup (defined at <ipython-input-147-bda858e4c00c>:1) ]]
     [[Adam/Adam/update/AssignSubVariableOp/_37]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_97424]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node sequential_10/embedding_10/embedding_lookup:
 sequential_10/embedding_10/embedding_lookup/91094 (defined at /usr/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py:112)

Input Source operations connected to node sequential_10/embedding_10/embedding_lookup:
 sequential_10/embedding_10/embedding_lookup/91094 (defined at /usr/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py:112)

Function call stack:
train_function -> train_function
```

I tried to look up for solutions online and found some posts but with no clear solutions. Some people suggest to downgrade tensorflow and the OP said it doesn't work. Some says that the shapes are inconsistent. The only difference between the word-model (which worked but was too big to run) and this one is the shapes are different as I have a small vocabulary of letters and some special characters unlike unique words, and choices of hyperparameters.

Comment: If you use Embedding with a given vocabulary size S, your indices must be all between 0 and less than S, you have negative indices which produce the error.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But what do you mean by indices exactly ? indices of which list/array ? Because I assumed that you mean the size of the Embedding layer should be less than the size of the vocabulary (although I read in stackexchange that it can be higher for character modelling) and still it gives me the same error.

Comment: I am talking about the input to your embedding layer/neural network (trainx), its a sequence of indices.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. But that does raise some issues in understanding the concept. Input length is related to how many characters I want to my sequence to be, I made it to be 1000 as the data average character per sample is ~750. If the embedding must be equal or grater than 750 then I must lower my input length or 'padding' meaning that I have to truncate my data tremendously isn't it ? Any smart idea to do this while not losing most of my corpus ? –